# mod-rewrite channel all traffic through one index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite, frameworks

OK, I have this mod rewrite (aquired after much digging: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?51923-Pretty-URLs-with-basic-mod_rewrite-and-powerful-options-in-PHP):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loader.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loader.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ loader.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It redirects all traffic to the loader.php in the public webroot of my server. The loader then loads the appropriate php file accordingly, pretty std stuff.

```
<?php
//load the definitions and functions
require_once '../www_private/functions/functions.php';

//If the user is looking for the index then the request will have been to a directory, add index.php accordingly
if ( is_dir(WEBROOT.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
    {
        //check for a leading slash
        if ( substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1 == '/') )
            {
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '/';
            }

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= 'index.php';
    }

//Now attempt to load the requested file.
require WEBROOT.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

The only problem is it also redirects css js and image files as well resulting in a bunch of fatal errors...

Does anyone know how to change the mod rewrite to allow non php files to skip this redirect?

or//

Would i be better to simply add another .htaccess file in the images, css and js directories to ignore the parent .htaccess?

Comment: By adding a new rule... RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|html|js)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including only .php files, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

$ Add this line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\w+\.php

# Prevent loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/loader\.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ loader.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a new rule to the main .htacecss

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|jpg|png|css|html|js)$

This simply adds a condition that must be matched: If the file extension is not any of these... As an image will fail the rewrite rule will not be applied to it.